# Qt: how to add a close and minimize button to a widget, that is embedded into another widget?

Tags: qt, widget

I want to embed some widgets into anothe Qt widget (into docking widget, for example). But I want to let user minimize or close them (just like the widgets on the right half of the picture)

[image]

Can you tell me, how can it be done?

Comment: You can use QDockWidget

Comment: Yes, I already use QDockWidget. I place a carrier widget on it, layout it vertically and place a few small widgets on it. But I want to preserve close button on the small widgets and don't know how to do it = (

Comment: You want to close the window, and leave the button??

Comment: Yes, I do. Maybe also it may be useful to minimize window and left a button to restore it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by using the [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#details)

Read this blog [How to tile widgets in a MDI application](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/29/how-to-tile-widgets-in-a-multiple-document-interface-application/)
here is Qt [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html) code